# Script para mostrar capital do estado selecionado?

Tags: javascript, html, script

Bom, queria que quando selecionado um determinado estado, mostrasse um alert informando a capital do mesmo. Desde já, agradeço.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Exercício</title>
</head>
<body>
  <select name="estado"> 
    <option value="estado">Selecione o Estado</option> 
    <option value="ac">Acre</option> 
    <option value="al">Alagoas</option> 
    <option value="am">Amazonas</option> 
    <option value="ap">Amapá</option> 
    <option value="ba">Bahia</option> 
    <option value="ce">Ceará</option> 
    <option value="df">Distrito Federal</option> 
    <option value="es">Espírito Santo</option> 
    <option value="go">Goiás</option> 
    <option value="ma">Maranhão</option> 
    <option value="mt">Mato Grosso</option> 
    <option value="ms">Mato Grosso do Sul</option> 
    <option value="mg">Minas Gerais</option> 
    <option value="pa">Pará</option> 
    <option value="pb">Paraíba</option> 
    <option value="pr">Paraná</option> 
    <option value="pe">Pernambuco</option> 
    <option value="pi">Piauí</option> 
    <option value="rj">Rio de Janeiro</option> 
    <option value="rn">Rio Grande do Norte</option> 
    <option value="ro">Rondônia</option> 
    <option value="rs">Rio Grande do Sul</option> 
    <option value="rr">Roraima</option> 
    <option value="sc">Santa Catarina</option> 
    <option value="se">Sergipe</option> 
    <option value="sp">São Paulo</option> 
    <option value="to">Tocantins</option> 
</select>
  <script>
    //É aqui a parte que não sei muito bem o que fazer
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Começa fazendo o `select`, é um elemento bem comum do HTML, você deve conseguir fazer sem problemas. Depois, volte aqui, [edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/197701/edit) a sua pergunta e insira o código que fizeste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Baseado no seu código, uma maneira é armazenar as capitais de cada estado em um atributo personalizado nos elementos `option`. No caso, eu chamei de `data-capital`. Com JavaScript, eu busquei o elemento `select` do DOM através da função `getElementById` e atribui uma função ao evento `change` deste elemento. Esta função faz nada mais que selecionar o elemento `option` selecionado e exibir o `alert` com o valor do atributo `data-capital`.

```js
var estado = document.getElementById("estado");

estado.addEventListener("change", function () {
  var option = estado.options[estado.selectedIndex];
  alert(option.getAttribute("data-capital"));
});
```

```html
<select name="estado" id="estado"> 
    <option value="estado">Selecione o Estado</option> 
    <option value="ac" data-capital="Rio Branco">Acre</option> 
    <option value="al" data-capital="Maceió">Alagoas</option> 
    <option value="ap" data-capital="Macapá">Amapá</option> 
    <option value="am" data-capital="Manaus">Amazonas</option> 
    <option value="ba" data-capital="Salvador">Bahia</option> 
    <option value="ce" data-capital="Fortaleza">Ceará</option> 
    <option value="df" data-capital="Brasília">Distrito Federal</option> 
    <option value="es" data-capital="Vitória">Espírito Santo</option> 
    <option value="go" data-capital="Goiânia">Goiás</option> 
    <option value="ma" data-capital="São Luís">Maranhão</option> 
    <option value="mt" data-capital="Cuiabá">Mato Grosso</option> 
    <option value="ms" data-capital="Campo Grande">Mato Grosso do Sul</option> 
    <option value="mg" data-capital="Belo Horizonte">Minas Gerais</option> 
    <option value="pa" data-capital="Belém">Pará</option> 
    <option value="pb" data-capital="João Pessoa">Paraíba</option> 
    <option value="pr" data-capital="Curitiba">Paraná</option> 
    <option value="pe" data-capital="Recife">Pernambuco</option> 
    <option value="pi" data-capital="Teresina">Piauí</option> 
    <option value="rj" data-capital="Rio de Janeiro">Rio de Janeiro</option> 
    <option value="rn" data-capital="Natal">Rio Grande do Norte</option>  
    <option value="rs" data-capital="Porto Alegre">Rio Grande do Sul</option>
    <option value="ro" data-capital="Porto Velho">Rondônia</option>
    <option value="rr" data-capital="Boa Vista">Roraima</option> 
    <option value="sc" data-capital="Florianópolis">Santa Catarina</option> 
    <option value="sp" data-capital="São Paulo">São Paulo</option> 
    <option value="se" data-capital="Aracaju">Sergipe</option> 
    <option value="to" data-capital="Palmas">Tocantins</option> 
</select>
```

> **Nota**: é possível recuperar o valor de um atributo do tipo `data-*` através de `element.dataset.*`, sendo `*` o nome dado ao atributo. Neste caso, `alert(options.dataset.capital)` também funcionaria.